# Mesh visible on object mode, invisible in edit mode

Tags: texturing, interface

I'm rendering a staff with a transparent diamond prism, and everything was working fine until I noticed, while animating, that the crystal was suddenly displaying its texture as though it were opaque.
[image: visible in object mode]

When I examined the object in edit mode, I noticed that it was invisible. Attempting to select all vertices with "a" and using "alt+h" to see if they were hidden in edit mode did not solve the problem
[image: invisible in edit mode]

I checked the texture the crystal is bound to just to make sure that it was transparent.
[image: transparent texture]

What would cause the object to be invisible in edit mode? And why wouldn't it display with its proper opacity?

Here's the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30844
imgur album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CaaV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crystal mesh is there, but because it's position depends on the armature modifier and the object controlling it, the crystal shows in it's original place when viewed in edit mode.
[image]

If you enable the modifier in edit mode you should be able to see and edit your object normally.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

As for transparency, you have not enabled any transparency on the texture or the material:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Any idea why the texture would be opaque?

Comment: @StephenSchroeder , Yes: because none of the controls for transparency are enabled. See edited answer.